# Can any radio telescope be hooked up with the Very Long Baseline Array, or other interferometers?

Tags: radio-telescope, interferometry

[The Very Long Baseline Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-long-baseline_interferometry) uses both Arecibo and [Spectr-R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-R), the world's largest space telescope with 10 m diameter at Lunar distance, as well as many other antennas. Are there any particular requirements on the design for a radio telescope to be used interferometrically? Could for example the now operating Chinese [Five Hundred meter Spherical Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hundred_meter_Aperture_Spherical_Telescope) be used as a part of the VLBA?